# How in Vitest in Vue 3 to test haveBeenCalledWith example

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

I struggled with this a lot, even bought the course by testing Vitest in Vue 3 in Udemy, but nothing helps and works.

But in the end I found a solution, may be it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { beforeAll, describe, it, expect, vi, vitest, Mock } from "vitest";
import { nextTick } from "vue";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Component from "@/views/Component.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

vi.mocked('axios', true);


describe('do something somewhere', async () => {
  
    const component = shallowMount(Component, {
        global: {
            mocks: {
                getData: vi.fn(),
            },
            plugins: [i18n, router],
            stubs: {
                'button': true,
            },
            provide: {
                items: [],
            }
        },
    });

    it("should make a fetch call to getData using correct URL", async () => {
        const getData = vi.spyOn(component.vm, 'getData');
        component.vm.getData();
        expect(getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith();

    });
});
```